# Ionic2 how to enable swipe ONLY for moving back?

Tags: android, ios, ionic2, swipe

I made my app by using the below code at the first time.

```
ionic start MyApp sidemenu --v2
```

And I added several pages. Some pages having components to push to another pages. For simplification, assume that page hierarchy is like below.

```
side menu -> page1 -> page2 -> page3  
side menu -> page4  
side menu -> page5
```

In page2 or page3, I want the users to go back to page1 or page2 by swiping.
In page1, page4, or page5, I want the users to open side menu by swiping.
But in tutorial implementation, I always open side menu by swiping.

How should I do now? I am sorry for my deficient English.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyApp ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
     swipeBackEnabled: 'true' //here it will help you to solve the swip
    }, {}
  )],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [ MyApp ],
  providers: []
})
```

check this link http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/Nav/ you can make it enable for swipe mode